# AngularJS DOM injection

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If I register an element-oriented directive with AngularJS ahead of time, can I then simply directly inject into the DOM (e.g. via `document.appendChild`) a node matching the directive element (e.g. `<my-directive-name my-attribute='foo'></my-directive-name>`, and AngularJS will render said directive in its place (perhaps needing a manual digest trigger)?

**my-directive-template.html**

```
  <div>
    hello world
  </div>
```

**my-directive-name.js**

```
function MyDirectiveName() {
        return {
            scope: {
              'myAttribute': '&',
            },
            template: template,
            replace: true,
            controller: controller,
            restrict: 'E',
            // ...
        };
}
```

**Angular configuration:**

```
//...
angular.directive('my-directive-name', require('my-directive-name'))
//...
```

**Start DOM:**

```
<body></body>
```

**Then I dynamically append a child node:**

```
<body>
   <my-directive-name my-attribute='foo'>
   </my-directive-name> 
</body>
```

Then I do something to make Angular realize that something has changed (what is this?):

**End DOM:**

```
<body>
   <div>
     hello world
   </div> 
</body>
```

Comment: Could you post simple example and the required result? I think this should be very easy by using `ng-if` but I might don't quite get what you intend to do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding a new element into the DOM with angularjs does not initiate it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25613924/adding-a-new-element-into-the-dom-with-angularjs-does-not-initiate-it)

Comment: this doesn't feel angular at all.  I comment on at least one post every day about angular saying the same thing.  It is counter to the purpose of angular to manipulate the DOM except in extreme edge cases.  In angular, you should code against your data, not the DOM.

Comment: @Claies Please indicate how I can render into the DOM AngularJS directives when the directives to be rendered are not known ahead of time that meets your requirement for "feeling Angular".

Comment: I'm not even sure I understand what you are asking in your comment, but I've used templates and combinations of `ng-if`, `ng-show`, `ng-repeat`, etc. to render content based on data types in plenty of projects.  I can't give you a solution to a hypothetical "I don't know what it is ahead of time" type question;  why wouldn't you know ahead of time, somewhere in the flow of the app? you aren't letting the users pick the HTML they want rendered on the page, after all....

Comment: @Claies there are certainly legit use cases when dynamically adding content by appending it to the DOM and using `$compile`. Sometimes for performance reasons (as using ng-if requires those elements and all children elements to be compiled, even if the expression is false), or recursively nesting directives (you can use ng-include, but there is far less flexibility there).

Comment: @Claies OK thanks. The scenario I have is that Angular is configured with a number of directives retrieved programatically at runtime. Then, depending on a user selection, the relevant directive is rendered into the DOM. Note that the directives are not known before runtime, so I cannot see how to use ng-repeat, ng-show etc in my scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to be sure to [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) the element first before just appending it to the DOM. Here is a trivial example showing how you can use the $compile function outside of angular code (through setTimeout) to add to the DOM.

```js
(function(angular) {

  angular.module('myApp', [])
    .directive('myDirectiveName', MyDirectiveName);

  function MyDirectiveName() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<div>Custom Directive with {{myAttr}} as my-attribute</div>',
      scope: {
        myAttr: '@myAttribute'
      }
    };
  }

  // run this later.
  setTimeout(function() {

    var appDiv = angular.element(document.getElementById('app'));
    // Get the injector to compile
    var $injector = appDiv.injector();
    var $compile = $injector.get('$compile');
    // compile new elems
    var barLink = $compile(angular.element('<my-directive-name my-attribute="bar"></my-directive-name>'));
    var bazLink = $compile(angular.element('<my-directive-name my-attribute="baz"></my-directive-name>'));

    // append both elements by linking against scope
    appDiv.append(barLink(appDiv.scope()));
    appDiv.append(bazLink(appDiv.scope()));
  }, 3000);
}(angular));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" id="app">
  <my-directive-name my-attribute="foo"></my-directive-name>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `$compile` the element before you append it. Here's a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ftfish/KyEr3/

Duplicate question: [Adding a new element into the DOM with angularjs does not initiate it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25613924/adding-a-new-element-into-the-dom-with-angularjs-does-not-initiate-it)